# Controls do not show up when dragging from toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, webforms

When I drag controls from the toolbox to an .aspx page or the designer for that page nothing shows up. I am using Visual Studio 2010 with an existing website project.

** Update

It seems to work now... I'm not sure if this was specific to one project, or a combination of things.

Answer (score 0):

Is the project under source control or in a read only state?

Comment: It isn't under source control atm and I just unchecked read only on the root folder. I could edit and saves files, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think the project is so messed up it just doesn't work. If I start a new project it works, so I'm going to leave it at that